# Ray intersectObject with Particlesystem ( capture mouse click on ParticleSystem )

Tags: three.js

Is there any way to capture mouse click in ParticleSystem? With Mesh and Paticle its working fine but if i call intersectObject on a ParicleSystem the intersects length is always 0.

```
vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 0.5 );
projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
ray.set(camera.position,vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );
intersects = ray.intersectObjects( particleSystem );
console.log(intersects.length);
```

Heres is an example with interactive particles: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4253186/three/examples/webgl_interactive_particles.html
but its not working with the latest version of three.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ray.intersectObjects()` does not support `ParticleSystem` in the current version of three.js (r.53).

So the answer is 'no', unless you modify the library yourself.